# Facebook app developer

Tags: facebook

One of my developers would have created a facebook app for my project, but I can't trace back with which email account they had created it. Can we trace back using app id with which email account that app was registered?

Comment: Do you see the inboxes of the possible email addresses, or can you otherwise get noticed if an email is sent there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...I think if you are authorized user added in the app settings then you can access the app using

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX?app_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX- is your app id

Login into your facebook account first.